# C# Finding and replacing a part of XML innertext

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xmldocument

For a project I am creating an app that works with an open API that is connected to TIA Portal V14, PLC/siemens environment.

For this app I am basically building up a XML file from scratch.
To achieve this I created my own XML-library file containing blocks of XML that, with the use of System.XML, I can copy into a template to eventually create a XML file that can generate a screen with objects in Tia Portal.

The problem I am running into is I can't seem to find or think of a method to find and replace just a **piece** of an elements innertext.

```
<VEG_Connection_Config>

    <!-- Static Properties hold objects with properties that are always the same -->
    <StaticProperties>

        <!-- List of static objects -->
        <GlobalLibraryObjects>

            <!-- valve -->
            <GlobalLibraryObject type="200" events="" properties="">
                <Hmi.Screen.SymbolLibrary ID="2" CompositionName="ScreenItems">
                    <!-- valve -->
                    <AttributeList>
                        <AboveUpperLimitColor>255, 0, 0</AboveUpperLimitColor>
                        <BackColor>192, 192, 192</BackColor>
                        <BackFillStyle>Transparent</BackFillStyle>
                        <BelowLowerLimitColor>255, 255, 0</BelowLowerLimitColor>
                        <BlinkColor>0, 0, 255</BlinkColor>
                        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                        <FillColorMode>Original</FillColorMode>
                        <FixedAspectRatio>false</FixedAspectRatio>
                        <Flashing>None</Flashing>
                        <FlashingOnLimitViolation>false</FlashingOnLimitViolation>
                        <Flip>None</Flip>
                        <ForeColor>0, 0, 0</ForeColor>
                        <Height>46</Height>
                        <Left>10</Left>
                        <ObjectName>DB_Stat_obj.$TAGNAME</ObjectName>
```

This is an small part of my XML library. At the bottom you can see an element called ObjectName, which containts the innertext DB_Stat_obj.$TAGNAME

$TAGNAME is the part I want to replace by a tagname I read off a CSV file.
So the end result should be DB_Stat_obj.1000P01 for example.

Now is my question if anyone knows how to use System.XML to find $TAGNAME and replace it with something else.

I am aware that with using System.XML.LINQ I can parse through the file and replace just that bit using this code:

```
string keyword = "$TAGNAME";
            var doc = XDocument.Load(screenLocation);
            List<XElement> query = doc.Descendants().
                                    Where(x => !x.HasElements && 
                                    x.Value.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();

            query.ForEach(n => n.Value = n.Value.Replace(keyword, objectName));

            doc.Save(screenLocation);
```

But considering my whole application has been made with System.XML/XmlDocument I can't use this code.
I have tried converting XmlDocument to XDocument just to replace $TAGNAME and convert it back, but that hasn't worked either.
Converting code below

```
public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument(this XDocument xDocument)
        {
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            using (var xmlReader = xDocument.CreateReader())
            {
                xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
            }

            return xmlDocument;
        }

        public static XDocument ToXDocument(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
        {
            using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDocument))
            {
                nodeReader.MoveToContent();
                return XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
            }
        }
```

I hope someone else has an awnser to this and can point me in the right direction.

TL;DR; How do I find find and replace a part of an innertext using SYSTEM.XML

Thanks,

// Jeroen

Comment: You don't. Use a `string` for the InnerText and then operate on that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´ll figure out that InnerText is just a simple string, so you can use String.Replace() to achieve the desired result